# cannot get the proper page after jsoup authentication

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I’m trying to parse an HTML page using Jsoup, i’m able to connect correctly to the page and get the elements, but the problem is that i’m getting another page elements

```
try{
    doc = Jsoup.connect( URL  ).
              userAgent(“chrome/34.0.1847.131”)
             .header(“Authorization”,”Basic”+encodedString)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .maxBodySize(0)
           .get();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Have anyone encountered this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why version of agent is too out of date? You said you can not connect correctly, why still get element? (Because I think if you can not connect, jsoup will return nothing). You should make your question more clear.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity, what i mean is when i do a get element i get the elements of another url and not the one that that i'm providing.

Comment: I think of a case: they are `http://m.example.com` and `http://example.com`. In this case, destination URL depends on Agent, you can set it.

Comment: when i try with `http://example.com` i get no result, so  i don't think it had to do with he Agent.

Comment: The first step, you should try to new userAgent, Chrome 34.0 is very old. What is your URL?

Comment: Getting unexpected elements ? Maybe a 401/403 authentication error response ?. Authorization header : you probably need a space between "Basic" and encodedString